# How can I highlight selected text in a cell and not the whole cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

In my Google Spreadsheet, I have a lot of text in a cell and want to highlight a small portion of this text with a particular colour.

But, whenever I try to do this, the formatting gets applied to the entire contents of the cell. Are there any settings to enable formatting for partial cell contents?

According to a discussion on [Google Product Forums](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/how-do-i/0bSf8jCKZrk), this feature was not available back then (till 2009). Has this feature been implemented yet or is not possible to do this at all in Google Spreadsheets?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible. You cannot format a portion of a cell's text. You can only format the whole cell.

Comment: My question was, How to apply formatting to the text after selecting it? When I select a part of the text in a cell and apply text colour to it, the colour gets applied to the entire contents of the cell. How do I apply the colour only to the slected text?

Comment: updating answer. You can't format the text separately within the cell.